# Unity Text Ui looks small on android device

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and I've developing a simple 2d game.
at scoreboard scene i've managed to save scores and display them on a scrollview. when i run it in unity it works fine but when i build and run in my android phone the scrollview looks a bit bigger and text ui (added by script) look very small.
Here is the code to display scores in content game object in scrollview :

```
void Start () {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey (0 + "HScore")) {

            float y = -30;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt (i + "HScore") == 0) {
                    break;
                }
                GameObject textobj = new GameObject (i + "HScoreName", typeof(RectTransform));
                GameObject textobj2 = new GameObject (i + "HScore", typeof(RectTransform));

                Text name = textobj.AddComponent<Text> ();
                Text score = textobj2.AddComponent<Text> ();

                GameObject lineObj = new GameObject ("Line", typeof(RectTransform));
                Image l = lineObj.AddComponent<Image> ();
                l.color = Color.white;
                lineObj.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (500, 0.01f, 1);

                name.text = "#" + (i + 1) + "- " + PlayerPrefs.GetString (i + "HScoreName");
                score.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt (i + "HScore").ToString ();

                name.color = Color.white;
                score.color = Color.white;

                name.alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleLeft;
                score.alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleLeft;

                name.horizontalOverflow = HorizontalWrapMode.Overflow;

                name.font = Resources.GetBuiltinResource<Font> ("Arial.ttf");
                score.font = Resources.GetBuiltinResource<Font> ("Arial.ttf");

                name.fontSize = 15; 
                score.fontSize = 15; 

                score.fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;

                textobj.transform.position = content.transform.position + new Vector3 (70, y, 0);
                textobj.transform.SetParent (content.transform);

                textobj2.transform.position = content.transform.position + new Vector3 (180, y, 0);
                textobj2.transform.SetParent (content.transform);

                lineObj.transform.position = content.transform.position + new Vector3 (60, y - 25, 0);
                lineObj.transform.SetParent (content.transform);

                y = y - 50;
            }
        }
    }
```

is there anything missing in this script to keep text fit with screen?

Answer (score 1):

You are using flat numbers, what you need s a percentage of Screen.width and Screen.height

For example if you are running in a phone with resolution 150x150 for example, if you want it in position 5, 5 you write this

transform.position = (5 / 100) * 150, it will set your object at 5 PERCENT from the bottom left edge.

Answer (score 0):

There is a component - Canvas Scaler on the Canvas. Try to to change UI Scale Mode - Scale with Screen Size - it must be on the Canvas. And also you can play with Math value
[Try to change UI Scale Mode - Scale with Screen Size - it must be on the Canvas.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgpRw.jpg)